# Проблема с файлом single.php - при переходе по ссылке на конкретную новость выдает 404 страницу

Tags: php, wordpress, error404

Создала страницу Новости. Сделала ее страницей записей. При добавлении новостей в самом начале всё шло хорошо - каждая новость выводилась на отдельной странице. Затем стала добавлять остальное содержимое сайта, в том числе и кастомные типы постов. Сейчас решила подправить стили на странице single.php. Но при переходе по ссылке на конкретную новость выдает 404 страницу. Пробовала активировать другую тему - там запись открывается. Но при повторной активации своей темы снова 404 страница. С чем это связано? Как это решить? Сайт очень большой - будет сложно всё интегрировать по новой.

это код single.php

```
    <?php

get_header();
?>
    <div class="page-head" style="background-image:url(images/bkgs/yt.jpg);">
        <div class="vertical">

            <h3 style="font-weight:bold; text-align:center" class="page-title">Новости</h3>
            <p style="text-align:center" >Ставропольская региональная физкультурно-спортивная<br> Федерация Айкидо г.Пятигорск</p>

        </div><!--.vertical-->
    </div><!--.page-head-->


    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main">

            <?php
            while ( have_posts() ) :
                the_post();

                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_type() );

                the_post_navigation();

                // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
                if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                    comments_template();
                endif;

            endwhile; // End of the loop.
            ?>

        </main><!-- #main -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->


<?php
/*get_sidebar();*/
get_footer();
```

Это код content.php

```
     <?php
/**
 * Template part for displaying posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package aikidosk
 */

?>


    <div class="col-md-5">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>" class="thumbnail">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-7">
        <header class="entry-header">
            <?php
            if ( is_singular() ) :
                the_title( '<h4 class="blog-title-news">', '</h4>' );
            else :
                the_title( '<h4 class="blog-title-news"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h4>' );
            endif;

            if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ) :
                ?>
                <div class="entry-meta">
                    <?php
                    aikidosk_posted_on();
                    aikidosk_posted_by();
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .entry-meta -->
            <?php endif; ?>
        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

        <div class="entry-content">
            <?php

                the_content( sprintf(
                    wp_kses(
                        /* translators: %s: Name of current post. Only visible to screen readers */
                        __( 'Читать далее...', 'aikidosk' ),
                        array(
                            'span' => array(
                                'class' => array(),
                            ),
                        )
                    ),
                    get_the_title()
                ) );

            wp_link_pages( array(
                'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'aikidosk' ),
                'after'  => '</div>',
            ) );
            ?>
        </div><!-- .entry-content -->
        <footer class="entry-footer">
            <?php aikidosk_entry_footer(); ?>
        </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->
    </div>
```

Настройки option-permalink.php не меняла. И, наверное, если бы я их как-то поменяла, то в другой теме мои посты тоже бы не открывались

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Здраствуйте. Хотелось бы увидеть настройки и код вашего single.php, для лучшего понимания ситуации. Вы настройки permalink не изменяли в админке /wp-admin/options-permalink.php?

Comment: Настройки option-permalink.php не меняла. Добавила код single.php, но не поняла где смотреть его настройки. Когда я создавала непосредственно index.php, то все работало. Не могу понять почему сейчас всё слетело.

Comment: Какие посты не выводятся кастомного типа или дефолтные? Раз в стандартной теме все работает очевидно что проблема в вашей теме. Постепенно откатывайте все ваши изменения,которые вы делали. Так вы найдете проблему или уменьшите круг поиска. Попробуйте скопировать из стандартной темы код single.php и заменить им свой шаблон. Так же отключите пока регистрацию своего типа поста.

Comment: Спасибо большое за совет! Действительно, причина была в одном из типов кастомных постов. Скорее всего, неподходящее было наименование. Сейчас всё выводится и всё работает.

Answer (score 3):

Настройки - Постоянные ссылки - Сохранить

Comment: Несколько раз пробовала. Ничего не получается